# Cron - schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Can scheduleJob take a callback function when the job is finished executed

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

 var j = schedule.scheduleJob('10 10 4 8 *', function(){
  console.log('Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!');
});
```

Secondly, what does it mean that the job is executed. For example the above job run at 10:10am on  4th of Aug. Does it mean that it will be automatically deleted after that time or do I have to call `.cancel` method? And what about a time job with the time `"* * * * * *"`, does it run forever if never stopped

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule ?

Comment: yes, edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The `scheduleJob` takes a callback function as a second parameter.

The job being "executed" just means the function is called (run once). After it is run, is doesn't get "deleted", but will no longer run.

The "cancel" method only works to stop the function from executing *in the future* if it is called **BEFORE** the next scheduled time. Calling it after the function has executed does nothing.

A time job with the time `"* * * * * *"` will indeed run forever until you call "cancel()" on it.

Comment: So is there a way to delete the scheduled job? I am making a task scheduler application. Jobs for a particular day are schedule at midnight at the specified time for the job. So after a job has been executed, does it stay forever or how is it deleted?